# Does deleting a playlist on YouTube also delete the videos?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I want to delete a playlist from my account, but I still want the videos attached to my account. Does deleting a playlist on YouTube also delete the videos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting a playlist on YouTube does **not** delete the videos in that particular playlist.

Comment: Like a simple "yes" or "no" and a reference to your answer would have sufficed.